# Binary , hexadecimal and octal values in mysql

Tags: mysql, hex, bin, octal

I am very interested in working with binary , hexadecimal and octal systems in mysql database. First of all please give me an advice why we need them during storing information , because of ton of information or why ?

Also which type of values must be stored in marked systems ?

In addition here are bit operator like "<<"

here is example => `SELECT 50<<2 AS example;`

this gives us result 200 , anyone can explain how it is calculating it ?

Thanks for answering :))

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4256657/632951

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First of all please give me an advice why we need them during storing information

Computers store data in binary.  Sometimes it's useful for us to think in terms of the actual *bits* that are stored, in which case our familiar decimal system can be a little awkward (as conversions are not straightforward); we could write the bits out in full, but that's often too cumbersome since even quite small numbers take up a lot of space to write (e.g. decimal `24521` is binary `101111111001001`).

Instead, we tend to use bases which are some power of 2, since they're more compact than binary whilst having the property that each 'digit' represents an exact number of bits in the binary representation.  For example, a hexadecimal (base-16) digit represents four bits (a "nibble") with the digits `0` through to `F` (decimal `15` / binary `1111`); an octal (base-8) digit represents three bits with the digits `0` through to `7` (binary `111`).

Our earlier example of decimal `24521` would be `5FC9` in hex or `57711` in octal: starting from the right you can see that each digit respectively represents 4 and 3 bits in the above binary representation.  Therefore it is (relatively) easy for us humans to visualise the binary representation whilst looking at these compact representations in other bases.

> Also which type of values must be stored in marked systems?

I'm not sure what you mean by this.  As indicated above, the same values can be represented in all of these systems.  In MySQL, we can indicate a binary literal by prepending it with `0b` and a hexadecimal literal by prepending it with `0x`.  MySQL does not support octal literals.

> anyone can explain how it is calculating it ?

The [`<<` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/bit-functions.html#operator_left-shift) performs a bitwise left-shift.  That is, it shifts the bits of the left-hand operand left by the number of places given by the right-hand operand.

For each position the *bits* of an integer are shifted left, the value represented by those bits increases two-fold.  It's similar to the effect of shifting *digits* left in our decimal system, whereby values increase ten-fold (for example, 50 shifted one place to the left gives 500, which is a ten-fold increase; in binary `110` (decimal 6) shifted one place left gives `1100` (decimal 12), which is a two-fold increase).

In your case, shifting the bits of the number 50 (i.e. `110010`) *two* places to the left yields 2 two-fold increases (i.e. a four-fold increase overall): `11001000` is decimal 200.

Comment: I've read also explanation like that for our example => Bit  operators  work  on  the  binary  representations  of  values.  The
binary representation of the value 50 is 110010. With the operator <<, the bits are
moved several positions to the left and zeroes are placed at the end. In the previous
expression, the value 110010 is moved two bits to the left, and that gives 11001000.
In the decimal system, this value is equal to 200. I see that two 00 are added on left hand side of 110010 and interested why zeros and not ones added ?

Comment: @Tomike: having read your comment gain, I now understand what you're asking.  The answer is simply that that's how the left-shift operation is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Your first two questions are too vague to answer, but the third one is concrete enough that I'll respond.

The `<<2` is shifting the bits to the left 2 places, as documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_left-shift). This is the equivalent of multiplying 50 by 2^2:

```
mysql> SELECT 50<<2 AS example;
+---------+
| example |
+---------+
|     200 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> SELECT 50 * POW(2,2) AS example;
+---------+
| example |
+---------+
|     200 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: so if despite of 2 it would be for instance 4 it will shift bits to the left 4 places ?

Comment: Correct. Try it out and you can see for yourself.