# how mysql treat the hex in sql statement

Tags: mysql, hex

I know a little SQL injection about php and i read some posts about sqli!the posts say when hackers want to get the column names of a table,they will use

```
select group_concat(column_name) from information_schema.columns where table_name=0x7573657273
```

in the statement "0x7573657273" is the hex string of "users".surprisingly，when I execute this statement in mysql console,it will exactly return the colunms of table users.
does it mean mysql will automately convert hex to string,eg convert "0x7573657273" to "uses" or convert "0x3D" to "="?
does it mean mysql can understand what the hex means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In string contexts, MySQL treats hexadecimal values as binary strings, where each pair of hex digits is converted to a character.

[Refer link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html)

Comment: does mysql automately covert to this?

Comment: Yes , check this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

Comment: But be aware that you need to [`convert` it to UTF-8 for output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256657/unicode-character-literals-in-mysql/28155621#28155621) if you use non-ASCII characters